# Error when creating DB2 service on Dedicated Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have already created a Bluepay account and transferred the Org I was working in to that account.

The thing is, when I try to create a DB2 service, I have 2 issues:

1. The monthly prices are shown for Singapore while I'm in Brazil and I can't seem to change the country.
2. When I click Create, I get an error: "The service instance cannot be created because paid service plans are not allowed."

Below are the screenshots:

[prices only for singapore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjmxl.png)

[error when creating service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjmxl.png)

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Cassia, Stack Overflow is for technical programming questions. Because your question is about an issue with your account, your best bet is to open a ticket with Bluemix Support: https://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport. You can also ask account-related questions at IBM developerWorks Answers: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/bluemix/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about pricing of a product/service.

Comment: I get it @ralphearle, I've posted it here because it was what the Support tab/link in my instance said I should do. No problem at all.
Just to clarify this a little, unfortunately the Bluemix Support ticked also doesn't work in this case & I had to use an internal forum.
If anyone has a similar issue, I think it's nice to tell them that, I can post the link here/name of that forum if necessary. And thanks a lot.

Comment: @AlexdaSilva, I understand, but my real problem is that due to the pricing plans, I am unable to create the instance so my hands are tied in going further with the backend dev. Since posting here can't help, I also agree to closing this. My thanks to you as well.